# IBM Worklight 6.0.0.1 - How to JSONStore init without server connectivity?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am trying to initialize a JSONStore collection when my mobile device does not have a network connection.  I have set the option, however, the init never completes.

```
{localKeyGen: true}
```

The same code runs fine if the device has a network connection.

Is there something else that I need to code in order to work with a local token while offline?

Comment: See my answer below, but need more code snippets on your part to be able to debug your problem. I suggest to follow the sample application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look at the JSONStore sample application? (to compare your code)

- For 6.0.0.x the sample is part of a larger zip file, that [can be downloaded at this location](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/wl_gs_all_samples.zip).
- I have tried this with the [6.1.0 sample](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/JSONStoreAPIBasicsProject.zip), but the code diff should not be drastically different...

The sample application is set to `connectOnStartup: false`, so whether your device is online or not, it does not matter. It is also not important to deploy the adapter for this specific issue.

In the `project > apps > JSONStoreAPI > common > js > main.js` I have added `localKeyGen: true` to the `options` variable:

```
var options = { 
    localKeyGen: true
};
```

This variable is passed while using `WL.JSONStore.init(collections, options)`.

I then built and deployed the project and continued to preview it in Worklight Console as well as test on an Android device (while in airplane mode).

I have entered a username and password (required if `localKeyGen` is to be used), and clicked on the login/initialize button, which passed successfully and the collection was initialized.

Comment: Idan,  Thanks.  I'll try creating a new simple project and see if I have any success.  One note, I currently am calling a function to do the WLJSONStore.init() from inside of wlCommonInit.  Thanks again!

Comment: Idan,  Thanks using the sample project with that setting worked for me.  I'll modify my app.  Thanks again.